# How can I calculate a list modulo a numer in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulo

In Python I have a list: `[11,42,122,1919, 17, 4]` and want to calculate its modulo a number (e.g. 10) to give the result as a list: `[1,2,2,9,7,4]`

Comment: keep looking, and look harder :wink:

Comment: I'm not a coder, so please just help me.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's a homework question, you can do it as:

`[a%10 for a in l]`

Comment: not sure he knows what that means, as per his last comment "I'm not a coder, so please just help me"

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without list comprehension, like this:

```
    num_list = [11,42,122,1919, 17, 4]

    result = []
    for num in num_list:
        result.append(num%10)
    print(result)

    # Output
    [1, 2, 2, 9, 7, 4]
```

If you're new to python then this sort of structure with code is quite common to use.